# substr not working with $item->getTitle

Tags: php, joomla, substr

I'm making a website with Joomla and am using RokSprocket to display some news. Now, some Titles are too long, so I wanted to shorten it after a certain character number, but it's not working. Am a total php noob, my apologies.

Here's the whole code:

```
<li data-lists-item>
    <h4 class="sprocket-lists-title ">
        <?php if ($item->custom_can_have_link): ?><a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>"><?php endif; ?>
            <?php  if(strlen($item->getTitle)>10)
       echo substr($item->getTitle,0,10) . ' ...';
    else
    echo $item->getTitle();?></a>
            <div class="date"><?php echo date('d.M. Y', strtotime($item->getDate()));?></div>
    </h4>

    <span class="sprocket-lists-item" data-lists-content>
        <span class="sprocket-padding">
            <?php if ($item->getPrimaryImage()) :?>
            <img src="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryImage()->getSource(); ?>" class="sprocket-lists-image" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $item->getText(); ?>
            <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
    </span>
</li>
```

I'm hoping it's something very obvious and I'm just being stupid. Thanks a bunch already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$item->getTitle` is probably a method not a property, so try:

```
$item->getTitle(); // <-- parenthesis
```

Change to:

```
            <?php  if(strlen($item->getTitle())>10)
   echo substr($item->getTitle(),0,10) . ' ...';
```

Comment: The same thing with the 3rd line `if ($item->custom_can_have_link):`, probably `custom_can_have_link` is also another method

Comment: Oh my God, that worked! Ugh, I feel very stupid now. Thank you so much! :D